# Find a value in NSArray [json]

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I have an array of json objects like this:

```
array : (
    {
expiryDate = "2016-04-22T00:00:00Z";
    id = "4dad2aeb-efa3-45ca-8d1a-7382851c56d7";
    name = "demo1";
    value = 200;
},
    {
    expiryDate = "2016-06-20T00:00:00Z";
    id = "28e0df69-3e8f-413d-a6c6-3d4cdad544f9";
    name = "Demo 2";
    value = 200;
},
    {
    expiryDate = "2016-06-19T00:00:00Z";
    id = "2e1f452e-ba53-4d4c-a4fa-e15442057b8b";
    name = "demo3";
    value = 214;
})
```

and I have a string `string = 2e1f452e-ba53-4d4c-a4fa-e15442057b8b`

I have to check wether the `NsString` is present in `NSArray` or not. I am thinking to convert array into dictionary and do searching. Please help me in this part.

Comment: Update your question with some relevant code. Show what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose your `NSArray` is array. Use below lines of code.

```
 BOOL flag= [array valueForKey:@"id"] containsObject: @"2e1f452e-ba53-4d4c-a4fa-e15442057b8b"];

 if(flag){
 NSInteger index=[array valueForKey:@"id"] indexOfObject: @"2e1f452e-ba53-4d4c-a4fa-e15442057b8b"];
 NSString *str = [array valueForKey:@"id"]objectAtIndex:index];
}
```

Comment: worked like a charm!! thank you very much for simple solution :)

Comment: and one more thing..how to get value of that if that id is in array?

Comment: Although this works on 99% of the cases, there are some cases when it won't work. `indexOfObject:` looks for, as it says, an **object**. In the case of string literals, this works, but if the array has a string not created as a literal, it will possibly fail. For example, take this in consideration: `@"hello" == [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"hello"]`, same string ("hello") but different object (returns `NO`). The correct way is to compare using `isEqualToString:`.

Answer (score 0):

The array represented by `()` is a usual `NSArray`, and you access its elements like this:

`yourArray[index]`

Being the index an integer starting with `0`. You could also go through the array using `for... in...` syntax which I'm showing you below.

The `{}` parenthesis represent a `NSDictionary` (key-value pairs) and you access them like this:

`yourDictionary[@"key"]`

Being the `@"key"` a usual `NSString`.

For comparing strings, you use the `isEqualToString:` instance method from the `NSString` class like this: `[stringOne isEqualToString:stringTwo]`

So your code would be something like this (considering it's an array of dictionaries):

```
BOOL stringExists = NO;
for (NSDictionary *elem in array) {
    if ([elem[@"id"] isEqualToString:@"yourStringHere"]) {
        stringExists = YES;
        break;
    }
}
if (stringExists) {
    NSLog(@"the string exists!");
}
```

Sorry about the formatting, I'm writing from my cellphone. If someone would like to edit it, I thank him/her in advance.

Answer (score -2):

```
NSString *str = @"2e1f452e-ba53-4d4c-a4fa-e15442057b8b";  
if([array[@"id"] isEqualToString:str]){
NSLog(@"yes.. string is present");
}
```